# Docker не получается скопировать файл в контейнер и проверить его наличие после копирования

Tags: ubuntu, docker

У меня есть docker image (https://github.com/reap/docker-glassfish3) в котором зашит glassfish3. Мне надо скопировать файл в контейнер dockerА, но сделать єто надо прописав инструкции для копирования файлов в Dockerfile. Я это делаю так:

```
FROM reap/docker-glassfish3
ADD ./files/ relativeDir/
RUN /create_domain.sh example 6000
EXPOSE 6048 6080
```

При запуске ошибок нет, а значит файл добавляет. Но найти его внутри контейнера и скопировать на хост я не могу.

Comment: `ADD ./files/ relativeDir/` скопирует содержание папки `files`. Если задумано иначе(скопировать всю папку), то надо `ADD ./files/ relativeDir/files` или `COPY./files/ relativeDir/`

Comment: а папка в контейнера создается автоматом мли надо лезть туда и создавать ее вручную? И как бы вы проверяли наличие файла в контейнера ? Например я пробовал команду docker cp, но постоянно пишет что такой папки/файла нету

Comment: Что такое `relativeDir/` ? У вас в контейнере вряд ли такая папка вообще есть.

Comment: @Suvitruf Хорошо, значит мне надо писать не relativeDir а "/" ??я с docker и ubuntu работаю в 1 раз и никак не могу понять что к чему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в контейнере нет папки **relativeDir**. Надо создать и копировать туда.

Что-то такое, если у вас **create_domain.sh** лежит в корне **files**:

```
FROM reap/docker-glassfish3
RUN mkdir /var/relativeDir
ADD ./files/ /var/relativeDir
RUN /var/relativeDir/create_domain.sh example 6000
EXPOSE 6048 6080
```

Вы пытаетесь запустить скрипт `RUN /var/relativeDir/create_domain.sh`, но, судя по комментариям, у вас этого файла нет в папке **files**.

Я бы порекомендовал для начала почитать основы [тут](https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_four/)

Comment: еммм...я просто не совсем понимаю вас..папка files лежит в папке с Dockerfile на хост машине

Comment: @andrey_KU в папке **files** есть файл **create_domain.sh**? Если да, то попробуйте мой ответ.

Comment: его там нет, я туда положил hello3.war который мне надо добавить в контейнер.

Comment: @andrey_KU а где тогда **create_domain.sh** ?

Comment: чесно, я без понятия...я новый в этом и самому разобраться тяжело..буду признателен если в этом поможете вы.

Comment: я нашел на github репозиторий с которого я тянул эту всю кашу..и там есть данный файл..мне надо его добавить в папку files?

Comment: @andrey_KU там не получится. Это сложная наука. Я бы порекомендовал доки почитать для начала https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_four/

Comment: @andrey_KU я не знаю даже чего вы хотите добиться. Вы сами знаете, что этот файл должен делать?

Comment: к сожалению нет, можете обьяснить?

Comment: @andrey_KU откуда мне то знать? )

Comment: жаль(просто мне показалось что вы разбираетесь в этом и можете помочь..но все же спасибо и на этом

Comment: @andrey_KU я разбираюсь в докере. У вас же проблема больше с пониманием Ubuntu и баш скриптов

Comment: я понял, спасибо.

Comment: Что можете посоветовать почитать, чтобы подтянуть знания Ubuntu и компании?

Comment: @andrey_KU ууух, это ещё сложнее, чем Docker. За пару минут такие вещи не изучить)

Comment: я понимаю, но все же.я готов тратить время на такие вещи

Comment: @andrey_KU для начала отредактируйте вопрос и напишите, что конкретно вы хотите и из какого гит репозитория взяли всё это. Может быть тогда и сможем помочь. А пока мы не знаем, что это за **create_domain.sh** вообще.

Comment: я добавил ссылку..мне надо поднять этот образ, залить в контейнер war файл, убедиться что он там есть (скопировать его на хост)..ну пока это все

Comment: @andrey_KU что значит "скопировать его на хост"? на какой хост?

Comment: я поставил виртуалку с Ubuntu, туда же я поставил Docker вот мне надо записать файл в контейнер докера и скопировать его назад (в любую папку в Ubuntu)или другим способом убедиться что он есть в контейнере

Comment: @andrey_KU зачем вам файл туда сюда копировать?

Comment: чтобы убедиться что он присутствует в контейнере..другого способа я пока не нашел..если вы знаете-подскажите

Comment: @andrey_KU `ADD ./files/ /var/relativeDir` гарантированно добавит ваши файлы в папку `/var/relativeDir` в контейнере.

Comment: а что насчет того файла (create_domain.sh) ???это файл который относится к glassfish и отношения к Docker он не имеет?

Comment: @andrey_KU он копируется в контейнер и запускается там. Сам скрипт, судя по всему, настраиваем domain и запускает `${GLASSFISH_HOME}/bin/asadmin start-domain`

Comment: огромное вам спасибо.я разобрался .ваша помощь очень кстате)

Comment: @andrey_KU всегда пожалуйста (;